# How to BULK Read from Azure SQL server and BULK INSERT to Cassandra in Camel

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, apache-camel, spring-data-cassandra, camel-sql

I want to read 5+ million events from an Azure SQL DB table and perform a BULK INSERT to Cassandra.
The table has 2 columns.
I see the SQL component available for reading from Azure SQL DB. https://camel.apache.org/components/3.7.x/sql-component.html

Question: Consuming from Azure SQL DB

1. Is there a better way to read all the rows and store in a map considering 5M records ?
2. Is there a possibility to read messages in batches ?

There is a cql component available for Cassandra
https://camel.apache.org/components/3.7.x/cql-component.html

Question: Producing to Cassandra

1. Can we INSERT in batches ?

Can I use camel for this use case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each table in your Azure database, we recommend that you export the data into a CSV file. There are lots of tools and methods available that would allow you to do that. For example, have a look at [Import and export data from Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/overview-import-export).

Once you have exported your data to CSV, you can use the [DataStax Bulk Loader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkAbout.html) tool (DSBulk) to bulk load it to a Cassandra table.

Here are some references with examples to help you get started quickly:

- Blog - [DSBulk Intro + Loading data](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading)
- Blog - [More DSBulk Loading examples](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading)
- Blog - [Counting records with DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting)
- Docs - [Loading data examples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkLoad.html)
- Answered questions - [DS Community](https://community.datastax.com/topics/dsbulk.html)

DSBulk is open-source so it's free to use. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @Erick Ramirez, This is really helpful to get started. I was thinking of writing a java application, but this task sounds more easy and repeatable.

Comment: Yep, exactly the reason we decided to write an open-source tool for it so users don't have to reinvent the wheel. Cheers!